# In Ansible, how do I run a shell script inside a git-bash shell?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.11.0

I have a shell script that accepts 2 parameters that I want to run on a Windows host, but want to run it inside `git-bash.exe`. I've tried this,

```
- name: Run test script
  win_shell: "cmd.exe /c git-bash.exe /c/temp/test_shell.sh db_name /c/temp/db_backup/"
```

and get

```
TASK [qa-db-backup : Run test script] ******************************************
fatal: [10.227.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cmd.exe /c git-bash.exe  /c/temp/test_shell.sh pacs_live /c/temp/db_backup/", "delta": "0:00:00.328128", "end": "2021-06-15 02:01:14.466517", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-06-15 02:01:14.138388", "stderr": "'git-bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.", "stderr_lines": ["'git-bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,", "operable program or batch file."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Is this because the `C:\...\Git\bin` where `git-bash.exe` is not in path? I'm not too sure about the syntax either though.

Any clues?

**UPDATE**

Here's my simple test script BTW.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: test_shell.sh <db_name> <backup_path>"
    exit 1
fi

DB_NAME=$1
DB_PATH=$2

# Echo the passed-in parms to a file
echo "DB name: $DB_NAME" > /c/temp/$DB_NAME.txt
echo "DB path: $DB_PATH" >> /c/temp/$DB_PATH.txt
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  touch /c/temp/fail.txt
fi
```

I modified my task to this, and don't get the error, but I don't see the files created in either pass/fail scenario. So I'm still not sure about the syntax?

```
- name: Run test script
  win_shell: "cmd.exe /c 'c:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe' /c/temp/test_shell.sh db_name /c/temp/db_backup/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*be aware I don't have a Windows machine against which to try this, so it's just "best effort"*

As best I can tell, your problem is because you are trying to recreate the behavior of `win_shell` by "manually" invoking that improperly quoted `cmd.exe /c` business, ending up with `cmd.exe /c "cmd.exe /c whatever"`; dialing up the ansible verbosity `-vv` could confirm or deny that pattern

Also, the [`win_shell` docs say](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html#notes) to use [`win_command:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_command_module.html) unless you have a shell redirect need, which as written your task does not.

```yaml
# you may save yourself a lot of heartache my ensuring that path exists first
# https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_stat_module.html
- name: see if git-bash exists
  win_stat:
    path: 'c:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'
  register: git_bash_st

- name: ensure that git-bash exists
  assert:
    that:
    - git_bash_st.stat.exists

# Modified afer adding "C:\Program Files\Git" to the system path  
- win_command: 'git-bash.exe /c/temp/test_shell.sh db_name /c/temp/db_backup/'
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't like the space in `c:\Program Files\...` I get an error that has `\"Could not find file 'c:\\Program.exe'.`

Comment: A workaround was to add `C:\Program Files\Git` to the system path, and it worked!

Comment: Another thing you can do, without needing it in your path, and to show you can chain commands together:
C:\'Program Files'\Git\git-bash.exe -c 'cd /c/Temp; echo "hello" > file.txt'